# ERROR: : Syntax error: Exception parsing query near '''

Tags: parsing, npgsql, denodo

`Npgsql` executing update statement to denodo view was failed as syntax error as

```
"ERROR:  : Syntax error: Exception parsing query near '''". When debug, I saw below translated sql statement which was pass to denodo from Npgsql parser.
"update testdenodoupdate set TestValue = ((E'aa')::text) where id = ((1)::int4);"
```

Due to `denodo` not recognising the statement, it was failed.

Kindly help suggest is there any other alternative solution?
My testing code provided as below:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Port=9996;Database=xxx;User Id=xx;Password=xx;CommandTimeout=40;");

    conn.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("update testdenodoupdate set TestValue = :TestValue where id = :id;", conn);
    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("TestValue",             NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
    command.Parameters[0].Value = "aa";
    command.Parameters[0].SourceColumn = "TestValue";

    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
    command.Parameters[1].Value = 1;
    command.Parameters[1].SourceColumn = "id";

    ssUpdatedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Try removing the `;`

Comment: giving same error, Mat.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of Denodo, just select operations worked through Npgsql data provider. Latest updates includes support to whole CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the new 3.0.0-beta0001 version recently published? Parameter handling has changed significantly and the problem may no longer be there.